# Recurring Events

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I have a webpart in which I filter the calendar to only include events for "today and tomorrow."

I would also like to include recurring events into this filter and haven't been able to figure out exactly how.  I know the issue is because the "Start date" corresponds with the very first event in the series.

I then tried to set the "recurrence" column `is equal to` and then I pasted the rule `Every 1 month(s) on the first Monday.` That didn't work because it seems to require either a Yes or No.

Finally, I tried simply setting the recurrence column as `equal` to `Yes`, and then it just gave me ALL the recurring events- but I just want the ones that are need for Today and Tomorrow.

Is there something else I can try?